# fuerte on lucid: pr2_simulator deb package is gone?

Tags: gazebo, ubuntu, ubuntu-lucid, ros-fuerte, plugin

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

a recent update of fuerte on lucid seems to remove the **pr2_simulator** stack, which unfortunately also means that the pr2_gazebo_plugins package is gone. Even if I dont have a pr2, I was using the **gazebo_ros_contoller_manager** plugin in my simulation. Now it has been removed, which leaves me somehow lost. Does anybody know whether this was by some intention or is it just a bug?

Best

Georg

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/46705/fuerte-on-lucid:-pr2_simulator-deb-package-is-gone!?/) by [Georg](https://answers.ros.org/users/171/georg/) on ROS Answers with karma: 328 on 2012-10-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Today, the package magically reappeared, so I could install it again!

---

Originally posted by [Georg](https://answers.ros.org/users/171/georg/) with karma: 328 on 2012-10-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0